# Using dataAnnonation regular expression validation attribute in Wpf Mvvm IdataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, mvvm

I'm newbie to wpf app development using mvvm. So please ignore if I am asking something out of the box. I have a model class where I am validating the data using data annotations.

**Here is the code part of model class**

```
/// <summary>
    /// The firstname of the person.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name must not be empty.")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum of 20 characters is allowed.")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The lastname of the person.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Address must not be empt.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum of 20 characters is allowed.")]
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
```

My validation is bound totally fine to the xaml, works fine and shows errors in text boxes in case of "Required and Maxlength Attributes". Now I want to use **Regular Expression Attribute** with my phone number in model class. Like

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Phone Num must be numeric")]
[MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum of 20 characters is allowed.")]
public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
```

**Here is the code of IDataErrorInfo in my BaseModel class.**

```
using Annotations;

/// <summary>
/// Abstract base class for all models.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    #region constants

    private static List<PropertyInfo> _propertyInfos;

    #endregion

    #region events

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region constructors and destructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public BaseModel()
    {
        InitCommands();
    }

    #endregion

    #region explicit interfaces

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an error message indicating what is wrong with this object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An error message indicating what is wrong with this object. The default is an empty string ("").
    /// </returns>
    public string Error => string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the error message for the property with the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The error message for the property. The default is an empty string ("").
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="columnName">The name of the property whose error message to get. </param>
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            CollectErrors();
            return Errors.ContainsKey(columnName) ? Errors[columnName] : string.Empty;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Override this method in derived types to initialize command logic.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void InitCommands()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Can be overridden by derived types to react on the finisihing of error-collections.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnErrorsCollected()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="PropertyChanged" /> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property which value has changed.</param>
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is called by the indexer to collect all errors and not only the one for a special field.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Because <see cref="HasErrors" /> depends on the <see cref="Errors" /> dictionary this
    /// ensures that controls like buttons can switch their state accordingly.
    /// </remarks>
    private void CollectErrors()
    {
        Errors.Clear();
        PropertyInfos.ForEach(
            prop =>
            {
                var currentValue = prop.GetValue(this);
                var requiredAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>();
                var maxLenAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();

                if (requiredAttr != null)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty))
                    {
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, requiredAttr.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                if (maxLenAttr != null)
                {
                    if ((currentValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty).Length > maxLenAttr.Length)
                    {
                        Errors.Add(prop.Name, maxLenAttr.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }


                // further attributes
            });
        // we have to this because the Dictionary does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged            
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOk));
        // commands do not recognize property changes automatically
        OnErrorsCollected();
    }

    #endregion

    #region properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether this instance has any errors.
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasErrors => Errors.Any();

    /// <summary>
    /// The opposite of <see cref="HasErrors" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Exists for convenient binding only.
    /// </remarks>
    public bool IsOk => !HasErrors;

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a list of all properties with attributes required for <see cref="IDataErrorInfo" /> automation.
    /// </summary>
    protected List<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyInfos
                   ?? (_propertyInfos =
                       GetType()
                           .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                           .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true) || prop.IsDefined(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), true))
                           .ToList());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A dictionary of current errors with the name of the error-field as the key and the error
    /// text as the value.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<string, string> Errors { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    #endregion
}
```

}

How can I add regular expression attribute in my Basemodel class? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding more or clauses - **||** - to your property you could just get all attributes derived from `ValidationAttribute`. All DataAnnotation attributes are derived from this class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a list of all properties with attributes required for <see cref="IDataErrorInfo" /> automation.
/// </summary>
protected List<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos
{
    get
    {
        return _propertyInfos
               ?? (_propertyInfos =
                   GetType()
                       .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                       .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true))
                       .ToList());
    }
}
```

If you don't like this approach you could then add an || clause by each attribute type you want to handle:

```
protected List<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos
{
    get
    {
        return _propertyInfos
                ?? (_propertyInfos =
                    GetType()
                        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .Where(prop => 
                            prop.IsDefined(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true) || 
                            prop.IsDefined(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), true) ||
                            prop.IsDefined(typeof(RegularExpressionAttribute), true) )
                        .ToList());
    }
}
```

As per your comment, I think that you need a generic way of validating your attributes or your CollectErrors method will get ugly pretty soon.

Give it a try to this approach taken from a project I developed using Prism. This code should go into your BaseModel class.

```
private bool TryValidateProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, List<string> propertyErrors)
{
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var context = new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = propertyInfo.Name };
    var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);

    // Validate the property
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(propertyValue, context, results);

    if (results.Any()) { propertyErrors.AddRange(results.Select(c => c.ErrorMessage)); }

    return isValid;
}

/// <summary>
/// Is called by the indexer to collect all errors and not only the one for a special field.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Because <see cref="HasErrors" /> depends on the <see cref="Errors" /> dictionary this
/// ensures that controls like buttons can switch their state accordingly.
/// </remarks>
private void CollectErrors()
{
    Errors.Clear();
    PropertyInfos.ForEach(
        prop =>
        {
            //Validate generically
            var errors = new List<string>();
            var isValid = TryValidateProperty(prop, errors);
            if (!isValid)
                //As you're using a dictionary to store the errors and the key is the name of the property, then add only the first error encountered. 
                Errors.Add(prop.Name, errors.First());
        });
    // we have to this because the Dictionary does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged            
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOk));
    // commands do not recognize property changes automatically
    OnErrorsCollected();
}
```

Comment: yes but how will I collect errors in case of regular expression , exactly like I am doing in case of required and maxlength attribute

Comment: @AmadZafar, I've edited my answer. I hope it could get you on the right track. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I get error in Error.AddRange where Errors is my defined dictionary

private Dictionary<string, string> Errors { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: @AmadZafar, since you're using a dictionary to store the errors and the key is the property name, then store only the first error encountered. See the edit. I'll recommend you to validate according to your needs.

Comment: I've done it sir. It works like a charm. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: @AmadZafar, you're welcome. Glad to help. I was putting a sample together to share with you. Happy MVVM-ing.