# Using dataAnnotation regular expression validation attribute in Wpf Mvvm IDataErrorInfo with different windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hore the more detailled solution! I use nearly the same code like shown here from Karel:
[Using dataAnnonation regular expression validation attribute in Wpf Mvvm IdataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642134/using-dataannonation-regular-expression-validation-attribute-in-wpf-mvvm-idataer/51373005#51373005)

and it works like a charm!
I have a Model where I want to use the Attributes and IDataErrorInfo for Validation which works perfect.

```
  simplified Model: 

  public class SiESTAModel : BaseModel
  {
         [Required]
          public string MyTestsceanrioNameTemp { get; set; }
  }
```

In my BaseModel Class I have this Code which runs:

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
        private static List<PropertyInfo> _propertyInfos;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Errors { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();


            public string this[string columnName]
            {
                get
                {
                    CollectErrors();
                    return Errors.ContainsKey(columnName) ? Errors[columnName] : string.Empty;
                }
            }


     private void CollectErrors()
            {
                Errors.Clear();
                PropertyInfos.ForEach(
                    prop =>
                    {
                        //Validate generically
                        var errors = new List<string>();
                        var isValid = TryValidateProperty(prop, errors);
                        if (!isValid)

                            Errors.Add(prop.Name, errors.First());
                    });
                // we have to this because the Dictionary does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged            
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOk));
                // commands do not recognize property changes automatically
                OnErrorsCollected();
            }


        private List<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos
        {
            get
            {
                return _propertyInfos
                       ?? (_propertyInfos =
                           GetType()
                               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)////////////////////////////////////////////
                                .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true))
                               .ToList());
            }
        }



        private bool TryValidateProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, List<string> propertyErrors)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var context = new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = propertyInfo.Name };

                var propertyValue = propertyInfo?.GetValue(this);

                    // Validate the property
                    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(propertyValue, context, results);

                    if (results.Any())
                    {
                        propertyErrors.AddRange(results.Select(c => c.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                    return isValid;


            }
}
```

This Model is created in my ViewModel:

```
public class DataErrorInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public SiESTAModel SiESTA { get; set; } 

    public DataErrorInfoViewModel()
    {
        // create SiESTA
        SiESTA = new SiESTAModel();
    }
 }
```

In my MainView I have some textboxes where a login is implemented and I check the Input Values. This Login is implementes in the View as an Usercontrol which works perfect for the whole propertiesin my MainView.
For example:

```
TextBox  Text="{Binding CurrentUser.SiestaIp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" MinWidth="180"  Width="AUTO" Margin="10,0,10,0"
```

But now I want to add some new Devices via a new window and I want to check also in this window the input values. I have implemented this with MVVM light and messenger.

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand OpenAddWindowCommand { get; private set; }

        OpenAddWindowCommand= new RelayCommand(() =>
        {


            MessengerInstance.Send(new OpenAddWindowMessage());
        });
```

Message:

```
public class OpenAddWindowMessage
{
    public OpenAddWindowMessage()
    {

    }

}
```

In my view project I have Message Listener Class implemeted like this which is called via a binding.

```
    public class MessageListener
    {


        public AddWindow TempAddWindow;

        public MessageListener()
        {
            InitMessenger();
        }
 private void InitMessenger()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<OpenAddWindowMessage>(this, msg =>
                {
                    TempAddWindow = new AddWindow();

                    TempAddWindow.ShowDialog();



                }

            );
         }
     }
```

And in this AddWindow view I have textboxes which should be checked for required to see on the begin of the post. The Data Context is also my MainViewModel like in my MainView.

```
        <TextBox  FontSize="16"  Text="{Binding SiESTA.MyTestsceanrioNameTemp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
```

Now to the Problem! If I only have the MainView Window open, IdataErrorInfo works perfect. But when the 2nd Window is opened and got the focus the get Value from my Property crashes out of the Base model.

Line of the crash:

```
var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);
```

Exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetException--> Object doesn't match to the target type.

This is because the reflection collects the values not only from the new opened AddWindow it collects also from the mainview Window my Loginvalues which I want only check if the MainWindow is open. And the getvalues from the the property of the Main View crashes.

```
protected List<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos
{
    get
    {
        return _propertyInfos
               ?? (_propertyInfos =
                   GetType()
                       .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                       .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true))
                       .ToList());
    }
}
```

So, what can be done so that the Reflection collects only the values from the actual opnened window? or can it be solved other? Thanks! I hope this explains nough :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to give us a [Mcve]. We don't have the context for the calls you are making. Given what you are saying, something is referring to your main view  it should be using your child view. Or did you mean viewmodel, which is where I'd expect this to be.

Comment: Hello Richardissimo thanks for the hint :) I will edit the explanation!